# How to determine whether a string contains newlines by using the grep command?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, grep

Suppose we have variable "test" which contains newline character, for example, `\n`. If I use the following command:

```
echo "$test" | grep '\n'
```

the result is not what I expect.  The above `grep` command only search the test string whether contains character 'n' rather than newline since '\' escape 'n' character.

How should I write grep command to search the newline character in specific string?
FYI, the following is not right too.

```
echo "$test" | grep '^.*$'
```

Comment: In general, `grep` is not usually the right tool to look for newlines.  It's original design was to read a line and see whether that line matched the pattern (and while `$` matched at the end of line, it was not really the newline that was matched).  Granted, GNU `grep` can do all sorts of extra tricks, but it still has a 'one-line-at-a-time' mentality.

Comment: What exactly are you after as output?  The lines that the variable contains?  A count of the number of lines?  Lines that contain only a newline and nothing else?  What is wrong with the output of the second `grep` command.  If there are three lines in the variable `$test`, it will select three lines, which is what your first command would do if `grep` could process newlines.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler what I want to knonw is whether $test contains newline character. I think wc command is helpful

Comment: `if [ $(echo "$test" | wc -l) -gt 2 ]; then : test contains newlines; fi`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler @eleven thought of how this could be done with `grep` and `cat` although `wc` is still the best solution for counting lines.

Comment: `if [ $( echo "$test" | grep -c) -gt 1 ]; then : test contains newline; fi`.  NB: my earlier one-liner should either use `-ge 2` or `-gt 1`.  Whoops.  The double quotes around `"$test"` are crucial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using the `-c` option of grep to count the lines that match this can be achieved. Note the `$` character matches end of lines not `\n` also see how the double quotes around `$test` are important for preserving the line breaks.

```
test="one
two
three"

echo $test | grep -c '$'
1

echo "$test" | grep -c '$'
3
```

You could also test against `^` the start of the line or `.*` anything, or as in your question, the whole line `^.*$` by using the `-c` option.

---

**How** about `wc` for testing multi-line variables. `wc -l` prints the newline count:

```
echo "$test" | wc -l
3
```

Aswell as `newlines` you can also use `wc` to count `characters` and `words` in a file *(or variable/stdout)* with `wc -m` and `wc -w` respectively.

---

**Or** how about using `tr` to replace `\n` with a unique character not contained in the variable for instance:

```
echo "$test" | tr '\n' '_'
one_two_three_
```

You can then `grep` for the replaced character, in this case `_`

---

**Or** even using `cat -E`

```
echo "$test" | cat -E
one$
two$
three$
```

cat `-E` or `--show-ends` displays `$` at the end of each line.

Comment: @BeniBela: which file?  Or are you thinking of a really big variable string?  Are you sure the cost of the extra process and the pipe would be a net saving?

Comment: @BeniBela I guess it depends what the OP wants, testing for at least one `\n` or counting how many...  (and @JonathanLeffler point).

Comment: if $test has some '_' characters, it will fail

Comment: @sudo_o if $test has some '_' characters, it will fail

Comment: @eleven yes in that case you would have to used a different character, maybe I shouldn't have taken that as given. Answer updated :)